# TSLint: for statements must be braced (curly)

Tags: typescript, tslint

I want to use this code to generate String.

```
randomString(): string {
    const length = 40;
    const chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    let result = '';
    for (let i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
  }
```

But I get this error:

```
TSLint: for statements must be braced (curly)
```

Do you know in typescript what braces should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (let i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
```

should be

```
for (let i = length; i > 0; --i) {
  result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
}
```

Your IDE should propose you to automatically resolve this issue.